# Reducer React, implementación typescript con interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, reducer

Estoy implementando un reducer para datos de la siguiente interfaces. Mi inquietud está en UserReducer.tsx, principalmente cuando quiero modificar el estado, con la action 'addUser'. ¿Es correcta la sentencia?

```
return{
         ...state,
      }
```

Porque el reducer no es un array de usuario, es simplemente un dato de usuario.

- interface.tsx

  ```
  export interface usuario{
    email:string
    nombre:string
    apellido:string
    foto:string
    calificacion:number
    tipoCliente:string
   }
  ```

*UserReducer.tsx

```
import { usuario } from "../Interfaces/interfaces";
type UserAction =  {type:'addUser', payload: usuario}

export const UserReducer = (state:usuario, action:UserAction):usuario =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'addUser':
            return{
               // usuario:[state,action.payload]
               ...state,
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

*UserProvider.tsx

```
import { useReducer } from "react";
import { usuario } from "../Interfaces/interfaces";
import { UserContext } from "./UserContext";
import { UserReducer } from "./UserReducer";

const INITIAL_STATE : usuario= {
    email:"",
    nombre:"",
    apellido:"",
    foto:"",
    calificacion:0,
    tipoCliente:""
};
    
interface props {
    children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[]
}

export const UserProvider = ( {children}:props ) => {

    const [datosUsuario,dispach] = useReducer(UserReducer,INITIAL_STATE);


    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{datosUsuario}}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> La función reducer regresa una copia del objeto state.

Aquí, se esta regresando una copia del objeto `state`, entonces esta bien códificado:

```
return {
...state
}
```

El objeto `state` de acuerdo a tu interface detalla un objeto `usuario` con propiedades:

```
export interface usuario{
  email:string
  nombre:string
  apellido:string
  foto:string
  calificacion:number
  tipoCliente:string
 }
```

También, `initial_state` usa la inteface `usuario`:

```
const INITIAL_STATE : usuario= {
    email:"",
    nombre:"",
    apellido:"",
    foto:"",
    calificacion:0,
    tipoCliente:""
};
```

#### Interface array de objetos tipo usuario

Ahora, suponiendo que se va a crear un **array de objetos tipo usuario**, se crear una interface `usuarios` que detalla a un array de objetos tipo `usuario`, esto debe funcionar:

```
export interface usuarios {
   usuarios: usuario[]
}
```

Luego, se tendría que modificar la declaracion de init_state, para que sea un array de objetos y no un objeto:

```
const INITIAL_STATE : usuarios[] = [];
```

Y el reducer recibiría este array como `state`, por lo que tendrìa que regersar una copia del mismo:

```
//usuarios en la interface
export const UserReducer = (state:usuarios, action:UserAction):usuarios =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'addUser':
            return{
               //payload trae un objeto tipo usuario
               // usuario:[state,action.payload]
               [...state, action.payload]
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Espero que la respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Lo que si no quiero crear un array de usuarios solo un usuario. En vez de reducer deberé usar un useState?

Comment: Si [la estructura del objeto state es compleja](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer), se recomienda `useReducer`, en este caso useState parece ser la opción a elegir.